# Meteor deploy - Error 503

Tags: android, meteor, dns

I am trying to deploy my meteor app named [dorj]  into galaxy.

I have my DNS at gandi, and set the dns : 
[image]

The strange thing is that I set  [http://dorj.memoranum.pro] to point at [eu-west-1.galaxy-ingress.meteor.com] where the app's name [dorj] disappear.

I deployed my app on both adresseses, with and without [www]:

1. https://eu-west-1.galaxy.meteor.com/app/www.dorj.memorandum.pro
2. https://eu-west-1.galaxy.meteor.com/app/dorj.memorandum.pro/

But with both apps up, I get an error 503 :

[http://dorj.memorandum.pro] => [503 Service Unavailable: No healthy endpoints to handle the request.] + url changed at [http://eu-west-1.galaxy-ingress.meteor.com/]

I guess I have a DNS mistake ?

App seems to be launched, they give me both the same success message  :

[image]

An error with the database (hosted at compose) could be that. But I guess the error would be different ?

What else should I check ?

EDIT

Deployememnt command  :

```
$ DEPLOY_HOSTNAME=eu-west-1.galaxy-deploy.meteor.com meteor deploy dorj.memorandum.pro --settings ./settings.json
Talking to Galaxy servers at https://eu-west-1.galaxy-deploy.meteor.com
Deploying your app...                         
App starting at dorj.memorandum.pro in memorandum's account in
eu-west-1.
Visit https://eu-west-1.galaxy.meteor.com/app/dorj.memorandum.pro to check the
status of your app.
```

Comment: Maybe the "Application process starting" is not a good sign => shouldn't the process go to "started" ?

Comment: PS : I stoped the [[www].dorj.memorandum.pro] app [dorj.memorandum.pro] is still running.